# How to set secret db password in docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new to Docker space.
I need some assistance here and my dockerfile code is below

This code is working fine but the password for DB I am passing is not correct, they want
to do give the password secretly, so people don't know the password whoever will see the dockerfile.

How can I pass the password correctly?

```
FROM postgres:12
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD Welcome123
ENV POSTGRES_DB POSTGRESDB
ENV POSTGRES_USER postgres
COPY ./Scripts /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Comment: The only ways to provide it as part of the image necessarily expose it in clear text.  You need to specify it when you run the container, possibly as part of a Docker Compose setup.

Answer (score 0):

Using [build args](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg):

```
ARG POSTGRES_PASS=myDefaultPassForTestPurposes
FROM postgres:12

ARG POSTGRES_PASS

ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD ${POSTGRES_PASS}
ENV POSTGRES_DB POSTGRESDB
ENV POSTGRES_USER postgres
COPY ./Scripts /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

You then build the image by passing an argument like:

```
docker build --build-arg POSTGRES_PASS=mySecretPass -t my-image .
```

Comment: `docker inspect my-image` (and I believe also `docker history`) will show the password in clear text.

Comment: I see, but his initial question was about hiding secrets from the Dockerfile.